# How to identify the areas to reduce over fitting?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, overfitting

I am trying classify CIFAR10. The CNN that I generated over fits when the accuracy reaches ~77%. The code and the plot is given below. I tried DropOut, Batch Normalization and L2 Regularization. But the accuracy does not go beyond ~77.

How can I identify the areas to be corrected to reduce over fitting?

```
convolutional_model = Sequential()

# 32
convolutional_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(.0002)))
convolutional_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(.0002)))
convolutional_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# 64
convolutional_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(.0002)))
convolutional_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(.0002)))
convolutional_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

convolutional_model.add(Flatten())
convolutional_model.add(Dropout(0.5))

convolutional_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
convolutional_model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

print(convolutional_model.summary())
convolutional_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=2, patience=8)
history = convolutional_model.fit(X_Train_Part, Y_Train_Part, epochs=200, verbose=2,validation_data=(X_Train_Validate, Y_Train_Validate), callbacks=[es])

scores = convolutional_model.evaluate(X_Test, Y_Test, verbose=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Please, ask just one question per post!

Comment: Welcome to SE:AI!  I'm leaving this question open pending more closevotes, but please consider reducing it to a single question.  (You can always ask additional question in separate posts.)

Comment: Edited the post to reduce number of questions

Answer (score 1):

It is a difficult task to identify the areas to be corrected to improve accuracy unless that area is looking into your face. By that I mean unless the regularizing parameter has unusually large or small values it is difficult to pin down and identify which regularizer to tweak. You need to do a grid search or random search over the hyper-parameter space to come up with an optimal combination of hyper parameters.

There could be a lot of things that you could consider to reduce over fitting. Some of them are $L_2$ regularizers, Dropout, depth of the network, number of neurons in the layers, the optimizer,  etc.